# Offline.js - checking while online?

Tags: javascript, jquery, offline.js

Here is my code below.

Simply, I don't know how to make it that if the connection transitions from ONLINE to OFFLINE, that the event which updates the css (https://github.com/hubspot/offline) will be triggered.

If it goes from OFFLINE to ONLINE, then it updates within 10 seconds. But I'm not sure how to have it work in the other direction?

It seems if I call Offline.check(); manually it will update, but ideally I'd like it to do this automatically. Any ideas welcome.

```
Offline.options = {
    checkOnLoad: true,
    checks: {
        image: {
            url: 'http://example.com/image.gif'
        },
        active: 'image'
    },
    reconnect: {
        initialDelay: 10, // only check every 10 seconds
        delay: 10
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Offline.on(event, handler, context)` to know when connection goes online/offline.

Like if connection goes offline

```
Offline.on('up', function gotOnline(){
  console.log("I am online");
})

Offline.on('down', function gotOffline(){
  console.log("I am offline");
})
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that didn't work though. I am testing it by using my mobile phone, and turning Wi-Fi off. I'd expect that would cause it to switch to offline, but it's not. I just never see anything but that green "Online" box. I don't know if it's relevant or not, but the app uses the appcache so it will work offline but I still need Offline.js so I know whether the internet connection is online or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation [here](https://github.com/hubspot/offline), You can see that **offline** has certain properties such as `Offline.check()`, `Offline.state`.

You can use either of these to display the `CSS` you need.

**For example:**

```
if(Offline.state=='down'){
    /*assuming that you have that div in your css set to hidden or something else*/
    $("#offlineDiv").show('100'); //Just an imaginary div
}
```

Then when connection goes offline..
Use

`offline.on(down, handler)..`

Now this handler makes use of that above piece of CSS switch to activate that div.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified in the initial message. I was using `Offline.on('confirmed-down', ...` and `Offline.on('confirmed-up', ...` as the event handlers. But neither these, or `up` and `down` are working when I'm making the Online to Offline transition. Offline to Online works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code using ternary operator

```js
connectionStatus = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';
console.log(connectionStatus);
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```