# Chrome - "disable cache"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, caching

I am using Chrome Dev Tools to debug a web app I'm making. I'm curious about this "Disable cache" button in Chrome Dev Tools:

[image]

Could someone please tell me what this does?

I've noticed some problems using Offline.js and discovered if I check "Disable cache" here in Dev Tools it works okay.

But what exactly is that doing? I am using Cache Manifest in my app so it works offline, but if clicking "Disable Cache" in Chrome Dev Tools is actually just disguising a bigger problem that's not useful to me.

Essentially what I think is happening:

- The image I am loading (see [Offline.js - checking while online?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29913099/2884981)) which Offline.js checks for to determine if the user if online or offline, that image is being cached
- Hence after the first load, it always appears online
- If I disable cache in Chrome Dev Tools, it works correctly because it's loading a fresh copy of the image each time.

Any words of wisdom are welcome.

Comment: The disable cache checkbox does exactly what it says - when you refresh the page with it checked it will request all supplementary files from the server again, instead of reading the previous version of them from the cache.

Comment: Just to add _Disable cache is only active while devtools is open._

Comment: Here's my problem though - that is okay if Dev Tools is open. But for a regular person using my web app, they can't temporarily disable cache so this image will be able to be reloaded. I need to try and get this to happen automatically in the background. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: hi @b85411   did u get a proper answer to you wuestion , i am facing the same situation when i run my code and i dont want the cache to tell the client to disable their cahe eatch time they load my site!! :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *disable cache* checkbox **disable cache**, it means every time you connect a server, you will download again the WHOLE website, even already downloaded images.

This may be used when you debug an application that have cache problem (you have cached informations & parsing them but the real data has been changed)