# Offline.js Cross-domain Image gives undefined

Tags: javascript, offline.js

I want my web app to know if it's online (to avoid my Google maps functions), so I use [Offline.js](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/).  I'm trying to access an image from our website, but the web app is not hosted online (it's run locally), so the access is cross-domain.  Here is my code in `$(document).one('ready',`:

```
Offline.options = {
    checks: {
        image: {
            url: 'http://www.portalogic.info/Images/portalogic.gif'
        },
        active: 'image'
    }
};

var on_line = Offline.check();
console.log(on_line);
```

But `on_line = undefined`.  Why is this?  Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Looking at the docs, I don't see anything about `check` returning a value. I *do* see `Offline.on("confirmed-up", function() { ... })` is valid event listener, though. (As is `confirmed-down`, and many others.)

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913099/offline-js-checking-while-online. And this: https://www.gavick.com/blog/detect-offline-browser